# Unable to get servlet request object and session

Tags: session-variables, servlets

i m trying to get session data,but i m not able to get it bcoz i m not able to get request object...
code is...

```
package secondary.util;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;




public class GetUserData extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware 
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private HttpServletRequest request;
private HttpSession session;
@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0) {
    this.setServletRequest(arg0);
    session = request.getSession();
}
public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return request;
}
public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}

public GetUserData()
{

}

public String getUserLocation()
{


    session = request.getSession(); // <- here

String []usr_dtl = session.getAttribute("USERDETAIL").toString().split("@");
System.out.println("User name = " + usr_dtl[6]);
return "DONE";
}

}
```

it gives nullpointerexception when i m getting session that portion i mark...

Answer (score 0):

```
session = request.getSession( true );
```

if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.

**UPDATE:**

your `request`  is `null` cause you never set the `HttpServletRequest` in `setServletRequest()`.

Try

```
this.setRequest(arg0);
```

instead of

```
this.setServletRequest(arg0);
```

Comment: i tried this but not working,and  i dont want to create new session..

session = request.getSession( true );